# How to bind datasource create in function javascript with kendo ui grid datasource?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, kendo-ui

I already have build kendo ui and javasript function. the function return datasource value. i want to bind this datasource value inside kendo ui grid. But i dont know how to bind this together. i want to pass 'list' in function inside my kendo ui. any help ? 
This is my kendo ui code:

```
              ` $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {

                                }
                            },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    ActivityID: { type: "number" },
                                    Assigner: { type: "string" },
                                    AssignDate: { type: "date" },
                                    Task: { type: "string" },
                                    Assignee: { type: "string" },
                                    DueDate: { type: "date"},
                                    CompletionDate: { type: "date"},
                                    Status: { type: "string" },
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

`

This is my javascript function:

```
  ` <script type="text/javascript">
  function retrieveList(){
   $.post("./proxy.aspx?func=getList",
    {
      Data: "{\"ListName\": \"Dummy\"}"
    },
        function(data, status){
        var json;
        var list;

        json = JSON.parse(data);
        list = json.Result;

        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample dojo for your reference which illustrates basic data binding to a grid:
http://dojo.telerik.com/aPoBiVEW

Answer (score 0):

i already got the answer !

Just add this code inside my function retrieveList and done !

```
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          data: list
        });

        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```